# linq remove items from query where any list value is present

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I am trying to retrieve this in linq but can't seem to figure it out. I want to filter a query based on if a value in the query exist in a list but remove those items from the query.

Let say I have a list of ids

```
List<int> UserIds = new List<int>(); //contains 1 2 3

var query = MyTable.Where(a=>a.Id.Notexist(UserIds))
```

basically I would want to remove all items from the UserId list from the query)
so query should not return items with Id = 1,2, or 3

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is this what you're after?

```
MyTable.Where(a => !UserIds.Contains(a.Id))
```

This will select everything from `MyTable` where the `Id` is not in `UserIds`.

Comment: @Jake If this answer resolved your issue, please mark it as accepted to indicate this to future viewers.